# PopupScreen not show after pushing

Tags: blackberry

I push the pop screen using following code, what pop screen not displays.
Please tell me what I missed.?

```
LabelField statusMsg =  new LabelField("Hello");
PopupScreen statusScreen = new PopupScreen((fieldHFM));
UiApplication app = UiApplication.getUiApplication();
app.pushScreen(statusScreen);
```

Comment: are you doing this on UI thread?

Answer (score 2):

Try 
 to do in following way

```
UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(statusScreen);
                    }
                });
```